# Aurelia Templating Engine compose

Tags: javascript, aurelia, templating

I'm trying to compose component dynamically through code (not with `<compose>`) and add it to the DOM from a service (similar to a popup).

From my understanding, the best way is to use the [TemplatingEngine](https://github.com/aurelia/templating/blob/master/src/templating-engine.js) via `.compose` method.

I cannot find a decent documentation or small sample on how this is used exactly.

This is what I have so far

```
constructor(
    loggerFactory: LoggerFactory,
    private bindingEngine: BindingEngine,
    private templatingEngine: TemplatingEngine,
    private container: Container,
    private viewResources: ViewResources
) {

    const hostee = this.templatingEngine.compose({
        host: document.body,
        container: this.container,
        bindingContext: {

        },
        viewModel: SnackbarHostElement,
        viewResources: this.viewResources,
        viewSlot: new ViewSlot(document.body, true)
    });

    hostee.then(x => {
        x.attached();
    });
```

I'm getting no errors and `.then` is being triggered, however, the component doesn't seem to be rendering. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: The `viewModel` should be a string path or instance. e.g `viewModel: new SnackbarHostElement()`

Comment: That's pretty much it thanks! Instead of using the `new` using the DI via `container.get(SnackbarHostElement)`

Answer (score 0):

This is the final code (thanks @Fabio)

```
async init(): Promise<View | Controller> {
    const viewController = await this.templatingEngine.compose({
        host: document.body,
        container: this.container,
        bindingContext: {

        },
        viewModel: this.container.get(SnackbarHostElement),
        viewResources: this.viewResources,
        viewSlot: new ViewSlot(document.body, true)
    });
    viewController.attached();
    return viewController;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just use the method like this, wishes to help you!

```
const View = await this.templatingEngine.compose({
    host: this.element,
    container: this.container,
    bindingContext: this.bindingContext,
    overrideContext: this.overrideContext,
    viewModel: this.container.get(CustomComponent),
    viewResources: this.viewResources,
    viewSlot: new ViewSlot(this.element, true),
});
```